# java regex search after a word

Tags: java, regex

I have received the following command from a given game server:

```
SVR GAME MOVE {
PLAYER: "player2", 
MOVE: "26",
 DETAILS: ""
}
```

Now I want to get the value of move using regular expression.
*note player name is a variable login name so it can also contain a lot of numbers.

I tried the following:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*MOVE: *([0-9]+).*");
                    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(parse);
                    if(mat.matches()) {
                        parse = mat.group(1);
                    }
```

*parse contains the string with the command.

Could somebody please explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: While regex can be used, you seem to be trying to parse some form of markup with it. You might end up wanting your own parser on the long run.

Comment: Whatever the server is returning seems like a valid JSON object to me. You can parse it as a JSON using `JSON.parse()` method and then do associated array like query on it.

Comment: Have a look at lookahead and lookbehind regex structures

Comment: Don't you see you have `"` in the string and no `"` in the pattern? Besides, `matches()` requires a  full string match, use `find()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the `"` in your regex:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "SVR GAME MOVE {PLAYER: \"player2\", MOVE: \"26\",DETAILS: \"\"}";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*MOVE: *\"([0-9]+).*");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(line);
        if(mat.matches()) {
            String move = mat.group(1);
            System.out.println(move);
        }
    }
```

Prints
26

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
String str = "SVR GAME MOVE {PLAYER: \"player2\", MOVE: \"26\", DETAILS: \"\"}";

    System.out.println(str.split(",")[1].toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
```

Comment: Thanks this made it a quick an easy fix

Answer (score 1):

The regex isn't right.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("MOVE:\s\"([0-9]+)\"");
```

With that, you will be able to extract the data. Also, you will need the use of `mat.find()` instead of `mat.matches()` : `matches` will return something only if the data match the regex, from beginning to end. `find` will scan the data looking for a subsequence corresponding ; check this for more informations https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html